# PCA on panel data with many IDs but only derive one principal component for each date

Tags: python, pandas, pca, panel-data

For the sake of simplicity and reproducability, here is the code for generating a sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'year':['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006'],
    'ID':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
    'factor':[np.nan, 0.45, .4, .2, -0.3, np.nan, .11, .21, .4, .01, np.nan, -0.32, 0.93, 0.66, np.nan, 0.5, np.nan, -0.12, -0.14, 0.36, 0.3, 0.21, np.nan],
    'return':[.11, 0.45, .34, .52, -0.93, 1.54, 1.01, .31, np.nan, -0.01, -0.2, -0.32, 1.94, 0.66, 1.34, 1.5, 0.1, np.nan, -0.14, 0.36, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9],
    'size': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
    'age': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 0, 2, 3, 15, 16, 17, 0, 1, 1, 2, 22, 23]})
data = data.set_index(['ID', 'year'])
data = data.fillna(0)

X = data.drop('return', axis = 1)

pca = PCA(n_components = 1)
PCA_PCs = pca.fit(X).transform(X)
```

When I apply PCA on the data, I hope to get single principal component for every year, but instead I get:

```
print(PCA_PCs)

[[-11.16171282]
 [-10.43225691]
 [ -9.7023714 ]
 [ -8.972357  ]
 [ -7.467887  ]
 [ -7.99143666]
 [ -6.48749078]
 [ -5.75773415]
 [ -5.02805484]
 [ -4.2978772 ]
 [  4.17395234]
 [ -4.20443643]
 [ -1.92727222]
 [ -0.42299984]
 [  9.59778387]
 [ 11.10139466]
 [ 12.60586466]
 [ -0.417883  ]
 [  1.08617458]
 [  1.81558753]
 [  3.31967947]
 [ 19.53355614]
 [ 21.03777697]]
```

Which corresponds to the total number of row in the dataframe. Is there a way that I can summarize or calculate a weighted principal component for each year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the first principal component as a new column to the original `DataFrame`. Then you can group by year and average.

```
data.assign(pc1=PCA_PCs[:, 0]).groupby('year')['pc1'].mean()
# year
# 2001    -5.726232
# 2002    -4.321416
# 2003    -3.502976
# 2004    -0.337490
# 2005     4.588059
# 2006    12.400073
# Name: pc1, dtype: float64
```

This is a valid way to summarize the data across years, as much as any average over a vector space. Which basically means it works if you trust and understand your principal components.

The first principal component will often just measure the average value, so you may just be showing that 2006 was larger than other years. Taking more components might help.

```
PCA_PCs = PCA(n_components = 2).fit_transform(X) 
pca_df = pd.DataFrame(PCA_PCs, columns=['pc1', 'pc2'])]

years = data.reset_index()[['year']]
year_pca_df = pd.concat([years, pca_df], axis=1)
year_pca_df.groupby('year').mean()
#             pc1       pc2
# year                     
# 2001  -5.726232  1.043865
# 2002  -4.321416  1.204462
# 2003  -3.502976  1.831200
# 2004  -0.337490  0.588444
# 2005   4.588059 -2.055726
# 2006  12.400073 -3.482995
```

Comment: Great, but I would like to have only one principal component for each year, which can be done by adding ```pcas_by_year[year] = np.sum(pcas_by_year[year], axis = 0)``` into the loop. However, this doesn't seems to be mathematically correct, is there a better way of summarizing the principal components correspond to each year? Thank you.

Comment: Got it. I have updated accordingly. As a side note, you should be careful that your input data for PCA makes sense as a spatial description. I think all of the variables, including `year` and `ID`, are being included. If you limit to `factor`, `size`, and `age`, then that makes the most sense. But this is already a very low dimensional space, so I am curious: why are you using PCA?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the update. I have set ```year``` and ```ID``` as index, so I assumed they are not included in the PCA input data? Please correct me if I understand it wrongly. This is just a simplified dataset, my original dataset has nearly 300,000 rows and 75 variables, so PCA seems to be quite suitable for it. Just that having principal components for all the rows seems wrong for me, as many other models only has one value for each ```year```, so I come out with the idea of doing this